# Session time out for Windows Authentication

Tags: security, time-out, session

I have a requirement where we need to timeout the SharePoint sessions (security validation). Since I am using Windows Authentication I am not able to use session timeouts (as Windows authentication uses http keep alive feature).

I am not sure if there is another way of timing out the sessions? Does SharePoint 2010 provide an inbuilt feature for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: i might have misunderstood your question, so feel free to comment or clarify if this is the case ;-)*

This is a bit tricky to do, since the session is persisted in the http authentication cache. The only way I have found to do this is using javascript on the client:

document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache")

If you look at the SignOut.aspx page (12/template/layouts/signout.aspx) you will see that this is also how SharePoint itself does it.

hth
Anders Rask

Comment: Agree with Anders, Windows Auth is not based on any timeouts so you have to create your own kind of session. The problem is that even if you clear the auth cache as Anders shows and you are logged into a domain and sitting within that network IE will automatically get a new hash to send to the server and automatically re-authenticate you. I suggest that you look into an ISA server or similar to make a safe solution.
/WW

Answer (score 1):

The "Security Validation" expiration is set to 20 minutes by default I believe.  It can be configured in Central Administration, Application Management, Web Application General Settings.

Since it is set at the Web Application, it is possible to have different settings for your different types of content and usage scenarios.