# Pinging a SharePoint Session

Tags: session, jquery

I'm looking for the best way to keep a SharePoint session alive using a jQuery Ajax call. We are embedding a large Flash report in a page on SharePoint and the idea is that when they click in the report (SWF) the page will notify SharePoint that the session is still active.

Ideally it would be as resource lite as possible and also return some indication that it was successful just in case the session timed out between clicks.

EDIT: I should add that we are not using Windows based authentication and instead are using a custom authentication provider with FBA.

Comment: What's your timeout setting on the Server?  I believe that is 20 minutes by default, do you think your Users will be idle for that long before making a request again?

Answer (score 1):

FYI,
Sessions don't really time out if you are using Windows authentication (security validation does, but you're re-validated automatically if you're using Windows auth).

See this answer: [Session time out for Windows Authentication](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/session-time-out-for-windows-authentication).

This may answer your question, but if your users are using FBA then you still might need to do something. Not too sure how the sessions are kept under the hood in FBA.

Comment: Sorry, I should have indicated that we are using FBA.